I cannot install "rms" updating R to version 4.3.3
I just updated R to 4.3.3 but I cannot find rms package. I get the following error. What would be the problem and what should I do? Thanks.
WARNING: Rtools is required to build R packages but no version of Rtools compatible with the currently running version of R was found. Note that the following incompatible version(s) of Rtools were found:

  - Rtools 4.0 (installed at C:\RBuildTools\4.0)

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding:

https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/Rtools/
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘rms’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at

I am trying to install rms in R.

Please download and install the appropriate version of Rtools before proceeding did you do this?

(1) It would probably make your life easier, if possible, to update to the latest version of R (4.4.1); that way you could install a binary version of rms directly from CRAN and not worry about Rtools. Do you have some specific reason you have to stick with R 4.3.3? (2) R is suggesting that you use this installer to install the version of Rtools that works with R 4.3.x ...

Thanks for the comments. I use R for work and we are using the available version of R from the approved versions of programs. There is a time lag. I cannot just install anything I want.  "rms" was working just fine before the update. I just copied the package folder from my previous version (4.1.1) to the new version package folder (4.3.3). It seems it worked but I am curious what the reason was.

Regardless of what you want to install, the installation of Rtools 4.3 is required for R versions 4.3.x. On Windows Rtools is critical for packages that need compilation, such as rms.

NeedsCompilation: yes

If you still get package ‘rms’ is not available for this version of R, try to install an older version of rms from source.
